# Assigning variables as lines of code

Tags: java, lua

I know in lua you can do something along the lines of
`print=System.out.println
print("Hello")`
But is there something similar in java?

Comment: Do you mean if Java has [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) that can be assigned to variables, passed as arguments to other functions, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) and [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

```
Consumer<String> print1 = System.out::println;
print1.accept("hello"); //prints hello
Consumer<String> print2 = s -> System.out.println(s);
print2.accept("hello"); //prints hello
```

Note that the type of the variable must be a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) (here `Consumer<String>`).

You can also create an alias for `System.out`

```
PrintStream sys = System.out;
sys.println("hello");
```

Comment: What does the 's->' do? also is it possible to do something like assigning 'sys=System.out;' and then calling 'sys.println("test");'

Comment: @ericsfinck `s ->` is a lamda specific syntax. `s` is the string parameter that will be supplied when invoking the lambda expression (in the example, on the line below, it is "hello"). It is also possible to assign `sys=System.out`, see my edited answer.